# How to post request per line in text file with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I created an username checker against the anilist api. It basically checks usernames for availability to get 'rare' usernames. I'm trying to speed up the process by using threading but instead of checking different usernames it checks one username fifty times. How can I make it so that it checks different usernames per request in the threadpool.

My code:

```
def req_split(r):
    global checked
    global available

    username = [line.strip() for line in open(f"external/{usernameFile}")]
    for name in username:
        data = {
            "query": "mutation($name:String){CreateUser(userName:$name){id name about avatar{large}bannerImage unreadNotificationCount donatorTier donatorBadge moderatorRoles options{titleLanguage airingNotifications displayAdultContent profileColor notificationOptions{type enabled}}mediaListOptions{scoreFormat rowOrder animeList{customLists sectionOrder splitCompletedSectionByFormat advancedScoring advancedScoringEnabled}mangaList{customLists sectionOrder splitCompletedSectionByFormat advancedScoring advancedScoringEnabled}}}}",
            "variables": {"name":name}}

        headers = {
            "Host": "anilist.co",
            "schema": "internal",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"}

        url = 'https://anilist.co/graphql'

        req = requests.post(url+str(r), headers=headers, json=data) 

        if "userName" in req.text:
            checked += 1
            print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Taken:       {name}")

        else: 
            checked += 1
            available += 1
            print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Available:   {name}")
            with open('external/available.txt', "a") as av:
                av.write(f'{username}\n')

data = range(0,5000)

with Pool(50) as p:
    pm = p.imap_unordered(req_split,data)
    pm = [i for i in pm if i]
```

Comment: I'd split the username list in 50 equally sized lists. Each of these lists are given as an argument to a thread (`req_split`).

Comment: Why are you looping usernames in the `req_split` method? Shouldn't you pass in one username at a time? What is the purpose of passing in the ints `r`?

Comment: @flakes the `req_split` function was originally the function for checking without the use of threading. I'm not entirely sure what you mean with the second question, but if it helps i found the threading method [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/52sius/comment/d7npetd/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: Hint: Print what your "url+str(r)" looks like. Haven't tested it, but this is my first guess.

Comment: @thetillhoff if doing `print(f"{url+str(r)}")` is what you meant, it prints out a lot of graphql links with random numbers behind it such as `{'https://anilist.co/graphql6'}{'https://anilist.co/graphql7'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break this out a bit more. Prepare the list of usernames, and then have the the `req_split` method handle one user at a time. Also you can do the post processing outside of the `req_split` method and avoid using globals.

```
def req_split(username):
    data = {
        "query": "mutation($name:String){CreateUser(userName:$name){id name about avatar{large}bannerImage unreadNotificationCount donatorTier donatorBadge moderatorRoles options{titleLanguage airingNotifications displayAdultContent profileColor notificationOptions{type enabled}}mediaListOptions{scoreFormat rowOrder animeList{customLists sectionOrder splitCompletedSectionByFormat advancedScoring advancedScoringEnabled}mangaList{customLists sectionOrder splitCompletedSectionByFormat advancedScoring advancedScoringEnabled}}}}",
        "variables": {"name": username}
    }
    headers = {
        "Host": "anilist.co",
        "schema": "internal",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    url = 'https://anilist.co/graphql'
    req = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

    return username, "userName" in req.text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open(f"external/{usernameFile}", "r") as username_file:
        usernames = [line.strip() for line in username_file]

    checked_count = 0
    available_count = 0
    with Pool(50) as pool:
        for username, available in pool.imap_unordered(req_split, usernames):
            checked_count += 1
            if available:
                available_count += 1
                print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Available:   {username}")
                with open('external/available.txt', "a") as av:
                    av.write(f'{username}\n')
            else:
                print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Taken:       {username}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand everything in the code except for `for username, available in pool.imap_unordered(req_split, usernames):` what does that mean?

Comment: @gxzs `imap_unordered` returns an iterable of return values from each call it makes to `req_split`. I made `req_split` return two variables `return username, "userName" in req.text`. The loop allows you to handle their responses as soon as they become available.